# Calculation between table with multiple rows

Tags: sql-server

I am encountering a problem of doing calculation between table in multiple rows.

This is my code:

```
UPDATE StockList 
SET stkQuantity = stkQuantity - (SELECT quantity FROM mCalculate) 
WHERE stkID = (SELECT stkID FROM mCalculate)
```

If table `mCalculate` has only one row of data, the calculation in `StockList` is successfully, but if table `mCalculate` has multiple rows of data, I get an error:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Can anyone help me solve this problem and explain to me what's the problem I am having? 

Image to refer:
Window:
[image]
Database:
[image]

Comment: your subqueries need a `WHERE` clause...  don't they?

Comment: hmmm... Maybe my brain couldn't digest what sir trying to say.
Can sir explain more? Thank you.

Comment: Maybe you should explain what you are trying to do. Your queries doesn't really make sense.

Comment: Are you calculating against the sum of all of the rows in mCalculate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use join instead of sub query in this case

```
UPDATE S
SET stkQuantity = stkQuantity - M.quantity
From stocklist s 
Join mcalculate m
On  s.stkid = m.stkid
```

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me. It works and I learned a new thing:)

Answer (score 0):

Among other issues, this line here:

```
 WHERE stkID = (SELECT stkID FROM mCalculate)
```

The `=` needs a single value, so unless your `mCalculate` table has only 1 row you will be getting errors.

Your error of: `Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.`  is most likely due to the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 0):

Your sub-select

```
(SELECT quantity FROM mCalculate)
```

Needs a WHERE clause that ensures this select returns only one row. Ditto for this:

```
(SELECT stkID FROM mCalculate)
```

Without the SCHEMA definitions for these tables, it's hard to help you figure out exactly what that WHERE clause should be.